# Java persistence date query

Tags: java, persistence

I have....

```
string qString = "select e from table where id= :id and trunc(Date) = TO_Date('03/04/2010','MM/DD/YYYY')

Query newQuery = entityManager.createNamedQuery(qstring)
newQuery.setParameter("id",id);
```

How do I set the date part rather than hard coding it?

I have tried
`newQuery.setParameter("date",date,TemporalType.Date)` but it hasn't worked for me. Any pointers?
I have also tried to use just 'newQuery.setParameter("date",date)' and used date as an argument ending me with...

```
string qString = "select e from table where id= :id and trunc(Date) = :date
```

, but I believe they aren't formatted correctly, what is the correct way to do this?

*UPDATE***  I am trying to do it with SQL date. Will keep you posted!!!

Comment: Have you tried using numeric wild cards such as `?1`?

Comment: what is numeric wild cards? I haven't heard of it how does it wokr?

Comment: `em.createQuery("from table where id = ?1").setParameter(1, id)`

Comment: hmm I don't need it for the id, rather i need it for the date!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is wrong with storing them in Strings just like you do the query??

```
String date = '03/04/2010';
String dateFormat = 'MM/DD/YYYY';

String qString = "SELECT e FROM table WHERE id = :id 
AND trunc(DATE) = TO_Date(date,dateFormat)";
```

Comment: Correct, That will work, but I think there is a better way to do this, I feel like good practices makes you learn more. I can do it that way, but it just doesn't feel right

Comment: I think this a better practice than hard coding the values in. If you want to change the values, you change them once at the top of your file and they are changed every place they are referenced.

Comment: I agree it is a better practice than passing in hard coded values, but i would rather pass in  plain date from setting parameters rather than passing in strings. Don't you agree it would be more feasible dealing with persistance?

Comment: Anywho, what I did was your way, but I will still try to figure out a better way!!!!